# How can I copy the screen represented output of showconsolefont to a file?

Tags: command-line, bash

**Is there an easy way to capture the characters that `showconsolefont` returns?**

Lubuntu 18.04.4

I am new to Linux but have a little bit of experience in a Unixish environment (macOS).

I am playing a bit with the `showconsolefont` command in the console and I would like to access some of the characters it returns. When I run `showconsolefont` in the console , the screen fills with a grouped list of 512 unique glyphs.

If I try to run `showconsolefont` from a GUI terminal I get the error "Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console." This is also true with `screen`, even from the console.

If I send the output to a file with `showconsolefont >> allglyphs.txt`, when I open the file I get a repeating list of 64 glyphs (I have tried opening the file with less, cat, and vim.)

I have tried calculating the offset of the characters returned and entering them manually with ALT . four letter key code, which works for ascii characters, but when I get the to special characters it doesn't translate, I'm guessing there is some mapping going on so the offset is not continuous.

Answer (score 1):

[The Law of the Instrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument): "If all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail"

I am providing an answer to my own question, but I won't be marking it as accepted, since it's a gnarly kludge that even it's own author can't love. I'm hoping someone offers up a much better solution; maybe some perl magic or an awk one liner?

Lets start with this somewhat related bit of knowledge: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/331317 it looks like there was a tool called `getunimap` that would return a list of the character mappings. Saddly this tool is not available in my distribution, and I wasn't able to find it in the package manager. I tried to clone and build [the source code](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/kbd/+copyright), but it failed due to a missing dependency and I didn't want to spend too much time trying to get the build to work.

The tool that replaces `getunimap`, `setfont` does not return the actual character that is mapped, only the equivalent unicode code point. Calling `setfont -ou chars.txt` returns us this table.

Enter my hammer; vim.

Here's the hack, [vim allows you to manually enter unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28925380/how-to-insert-unicode-character-u2611-in-gvim) by pressing `C-v` then "u" and four numbers. For example in insert mode typing `C-v u0056` inserts the letter W. The problem is, (at least in my cursory research) you can't paste in a value, it needs to be hand keyed. What to do? This `C-v` mode basically just takes literal keyboard inputs and drops them into the current buffer... what if... what if we create a macro that does the typing for us? What do we need? Enter insert mode, `C-v`, `u`, and four digits... thats it, right? Lets give it a try!

### First lets clean up the text

Open `chars.txt` in vim.
Enter visual block mode with `C-v`
Select to the end of the file with `G`
Select the first column and whitespace
Remove selection with `x`
`gv` to reselect previously selected text
Highlight only the `"U"` column
`~` to toggle case
Move the cursor to the `+` character
`C-v` to reneter visual block mode
`G` to move to the end buffer
`x` to remove the `+` character

### Create the unicode insertion keystrokes

`0` to move to the beginning of the line
revisit our old friends `C-v`, `G`
`I` to enter insert mode
`i` to enter insert when the macro is run
`C-v` to enter insert literal mode
`C-v` again to insert a literal `C-v` into the current line
`Esc` to leave insert mode
All the lines should now look like `i^vu####` where pound is a number.

### Execute all the keystrokes

`qq` to start recording a macro
`0` to move the beginning of the line
`"py$` to yank the current line into the p register
`@p` to execute the contents of the p register as key strokes
`esc` to leave insert mode
`l` to move a character over
`d$` to delete the macro
`j` to move to the next line
`q` to stop recording
`1000@q` to play the macro over all the lines

There was a real Raiders of the Lost Ark moment for me when I first did this. The first line evaluated to nothing. It turns out that the first character in the list was a space, so it just looked like the whole p macro didn't work. Sometimes you gotta just step out into the void I guess.

### Fin

There we have it, a list of all the characters that the console can display [in the most round about way possible](https://github.com/hakluke/how-to-exit-vim/blob/master/README.md)... with a few duplicates that `:sort u` doesn't seem to help with. Oh well.

Comment: bash's `printf` has a `%b` format specifier that can print unicode code points in the format `\Unnnn` - so given that `setfont` appears to output lines of the form `0xmm    U+nnnn` you might want to try something like `while read -r x u; do printf '%b\n' "${u/U+/\\U}"; done < chars.txt`